# Curl could not resolve host using Docker on WSL 2

Tags: docker, curl

I am trying to use curl to download releases from github and it cannot seem to resolve the domain.

I get the error `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: objects.githubusercontent.com`

I am running Docker on WSL 2. Part of my Dockerfile is below and it doesn't get past the `curl` command

```
FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk update && apk add curl unzip 
RUN curl -LO https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/releases/download/bun-v0.1.3/bun-linux-x64.zip && unzip bun-linux-x64.zip
COPY ["package.json", "bun.lockb", "./"]
RUN echo ls
RUN /usr/local/bin/bun-linux-x64/bun install
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case you don't use the Docker Desktop app and have installed Docker in the WSL2 Ubuntu instance, edit/create a config file: `/etc/docker/daemon.json`
and set default DNS:

```json
{
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
}
```

Restart the Docker service:

```
service docker restart
```

Answer (score 4):

Try configuring the docker daemon to use a default dns server by configuring `daemon.json`.

If using Docker Desktop, you should NOT edit the file directly. It can be edited from within Docker Desktop, under `Preferences / Daemon / Advanced`.

Else the file can be found (or created) at `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json`.

Configuring the Google dns server `8.8.8.8` in an empty file would look something like this:

```
{
    "dns": 
    [
        "8.8.8.8"
    ]
}
```

More information about `daemon.json` [can be found here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file).

Answer (score 1):

It's a silly thing to do, but check that you're not connected to a VPN or that it's not your internet service.